# trouble with installing fastcgi_cache_purge ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, cache, fastcgi

So I'm trying to install fastcgi_cache_purge which is supposely a third party module https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_cache_purge from https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/ but this would require me to recompile nginx or reinstall nginx from a different package which I don't want to do.

However from looking at my original nginx repo http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nginx/libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge_1.14.0-0+xenial1_amd64.deb  I found this mod which on description said: Purge content from Nginx caches content from caches used by all of Nginx proxy modules, like FastCGI, Proxy, SCGI and uWSGI. Which say essentially the same thing as FRiCKLE ngx_cache_purge. My question is, is it the same thing? If so can I just install it like so?

sudo apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge

anyone else encountering this?

Comment: It looks like someone made an nginx module out of it. I wonder if they documented their work anywhere, because that would be useful.

Comment: Funny thing is on this page http://installion.co.uk/kali/kali/main/l/libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge/install/index.html it say the mod is from nginx main. But I download nginx main package from its homepage and the libnginx-mod-http-cache-purge mod is nowhere to be found hmmmmm.

Comment: hey, take a look at https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster , a web cache supports purging